# Quiero navegar por las etiquetas de mi HTML y conseguir el texto de un span

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Necesito mediante javascript llegar al texto del `span` que esta dentro del otro `span`

```
<td><a id="espacio" type="button" onclick="{{ ($espacio->estado==0 ? 'abrirReservarEspacio(this)' : 'abrirConcluirReservarEspacio(this)') }}" class="espacio" style="{{  ($espacio->estado == 1 ? ' background-color:#f44336;' : 'background-color:#7E7E7E;') }}" value="{{$espacio->nomespacio}}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{ ($espacio->estado==0 ? '#reservaModal' : '#limpiarreservaModal') }}"><span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="font-size:5em;"><i class="fas fa-car"></i><span value="{{$espacio->nomespacio}}" class="fa-layers-text fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8 down-3" style="font-size:0.5em;font-weight:900">{{$espacio->nomespacio}}</span></span></a></td>
```

Al presionar el `<a>` se ejecuta un evento `onclick` donde se llama a un js el cual es este:

```
    function abrirReservarEspacio(a){
    window.nomespacio = a.closest('td').querySelector('#espacio').innerHTML;
    console.log(nomespacio);
    document.getElementById("espacioReserva").innerHTML=nomespacio;
    document.getElementById("nomespacio").value=nomespacio
    document.getElementById("texto-vertical").innerHTML=nomespacio;
    

}
```

Estoy intentando con `childNodes` e `innerHTML` pero no se como llegar desde la etiqueta `<a>` hasta el texto que hay dentro del `span`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en tu HTML, comenzando con que aparentemente estás repitiendo `id="espacio"` para los enlaces y este atributo [debe ser único](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id); aparte, el atributo `value` solo está disponible en campos y botones de formulario, aunque funciona, no se debe colocar en cualquier etiqueta y, de cualquier forma, o tiene sentido que lo incluyas aquí, porque el contenido es el mismo que el texto.

Por otra parte, no necesitas recurrir a la celda (TD) para llegar al span, porque este es parte del enlace. Solo hay que hacer referencia a elementos internos:

- `:scope` para buscar solo dentro del elemento actual (enlace)
- `> span` solo los span hijos directos del elemento actual
- `> span` solo los span hijos directos del span anterior

Desde el enlace usas el selector y accedes al elemento deseado:

```
function abrirReservarEspacio(a){
    // Obtener span con nombre de espacio
    let spanText = a.querySelector(':scope > span > span');
    console.log(spanText);
    // Obtener texto del nombre de espacio
    let nomespacio = spanText.innerText;
    document.getElementById("espacioReserva").innerHTML = nomespacio;
    document.getElementById("nomespacio").value = nomespacio
    document.getElementById("texto-vertical").innerHTML = nomespacio;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a añadirle al segundo span un id y referenciarlo desde Javascript con ese valor?

Ej:

**En HTML:**

```
<span  id="segundoSpan" ...</span>
```

**En el Javascript:**

```
var 2span= document.getElementById("segundoSpan").value;
```